# Background script event listeners break after error in pop-up script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have the following event listener in `background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(...);
```

It modifies the extension storage using the Chrome Storage API to keep track of tabs. It works fine before this happens:

[image: Error in pop-up script (viewing chrome://extensions]

Although the error is actually inside a pop-up script, the event listener in `background.js` stops firing after that and I have to manually re-import the extension.

Is it relevant if the error happens within a Chrome API function? 
How do I make sure the event listener keeps firing?

```
// manifest.json

    ...
    "permissions": ["storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "audio/Low_Woodblock.wav"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
           "16": "images/icon_ok16.png"
        }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: The question is not really answerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve) (manifest.json and the code). Right now the best guess is that you're incorrectly loading the same script both as the background script and as a script in the popup.

Comment: Added manifest.json to the question. What code do you think is important?

Comment: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`
I can't manage to check it since `chrome.connect` doesn't accept a callback... But that's for a different question

Comment: I thought the `manifest.json` will anser your question. No, I'm not. popup.html imports a different js file.

Comment: I won't be able to help without trying the entire extension. Right now I can't be even sure the error is related to the problem as there are many moving parts in an extension which can be used incorrectly. It can be also a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Alright, thank you anyways. I'll upload to GitHub if I won't manage to fix it.